# TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor when using Tensorflow's canned RNNEstimator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorflow-estimator

I am using Tensorflow's Dataset API to create a basic dataset and use it as input to the canned [RNNEstimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/RNNEstimator) as follows (Note some lines have been omitted for brevity:

```
sequence_feature_colums = [tf.contrib.feature_column.sequence_numeric_column("price")]  
estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.RNNEstimator(
        head=tf.contrib.estimator.regression_head(),
        sequence_feature_columns=sequence_feature_colums)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
estimator.train(input_fn=lambda:return dataset)
```

But I am seeing the follow error when calling `train`:

```
...
  File "/Users/luke/virtualenvs/smp-rnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/feature_column/python/feature_column/sequence_feature_column.py", line 497, in _get_sequence_dense_tensor
    sp_tensor, default_value=self.default_value)
  File "/Users/luke/virtualenvs/smp-rnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py", line 1449, in sparse_tensor_to_dense
    sp_input = _convert_to_sparse_tensor(sp_input)
  File "/Users/luke/virtualenvs/smp-rnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py", line 68, in _convert_to_sparse_tensor
    raise TypeError("Input must be a SparseTensor.")
TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.
```

What am I doing wrong here? This is very simple example following the standard steps for using Estimators so I'm not sure where in my code I have decided *not* to use a SparseTensor.

Comment: I struggle with the lack of good documentation as well. What the RNNEstimator expects here is that the data is stored as a dense Tensor so that it can convert it to a sparse tensor. The problem is identifying where the transformation is suppsoed to take place.

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?